# Git asking for password even after Public key is supplied

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've been trying to push my project to git but it keeps asking me for password even after I've supplied public key to SSH keys under profile section of git UI.I've followed the steps supplied by git to create and add SSH key to the NEW KEY option in the UI.I've been trying this for 2 days now and still can't fix it.I deleted all my past modifications and installed fresh git to my windows 10 and tried all from beginning but the problem persists.
Created key using

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "useri@company.com"
```

Added key to GIT UI by copying the key

```
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

When I try to SSH to git I'm getting

```
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to git.company.com [198.41.85.18] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to git.company.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:GeFkVDzGN7W8Ngp/osU5gqDL5jdf6GDgF8lLPWapDU8
The authenticity of host 'git.company.com (198.41.85.18)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:GeFkVDzGN7W8Ngp/osU5gqDL5jdf6GDgF8lLPWapDU8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'git.company.com,198.41.85.18' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/usernames/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@git.company.com's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@git.company.com's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
git@git.company.com's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Even while I tried to run ssh -T git@git.company.com

```
The authenticity of host 'git.company.com (198.41.85.18)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:GeFkVDzGN7W8Ngp/osU5gqDL5jdf6GDgF8lLPWapDU8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'git.company.com,198.41.85.18' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@git.company.com's password:
```

Hers's my ssh_conf file from etc/ssh

```
#$OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.28 2013/09/16 11:35:43 sthen Exp $
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I generated it at my Local machine

Comment: Clearly the server does not accept your key. Since you don't mention, is the key authorized on the server at all? Also there may be a typo in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` (on the server; perhaps some editor inserted a newline or something) or the `.ssh` directory may have incorrect permissions (it must _not_ be writable by either group nor others).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). fatal: Could not read from remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291143/permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic-password-fatal-coul)

Answer (score 0):

Set your keys (few options:)

#### Create a SSH config file

> You can construct a SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.
>
> The format for the alias entries use in this example is:
>
> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName bitbucket.org 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```
>
> To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

---

#### Add your keys to your github account.

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

Comment: OKAY.i'LL TRY THAT AND WILL BE BACK AS SOON AS POSSIBLE